# Drupal 8 Metatag tokens

Tags: drupal-8

Does anyone know how to essentially unserialize a Drupal Token? Using the Metatag module, I'm trying to access the meta description like so:

```
[node:field_job_description:entity:field_job_description_meta:value]
```

But it renders out like this ...

```
a:1:{s:11:&quot;description&quot;;s:329:&quot;Looking for a ...
```

There are a couple issues around it on the Metatag project already, but none have any solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: where did you try this? in a module ?

Comment: @Yusef - Used it as a property setting with tokens (just in the UI) ... Seems it's a known issue:
https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2862747